# Resolve absolute paths with rollup

Tags: build, rollupjs

Using absolute path in my package like this `import { Component1, Component2 } from "common/assets";`

And get error after local install and check

> ./node_modules/package/dist/package.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'common/assets' in '/home/max/project/node_modules/package/dist'

In during assembly get warnings

> (!) Unresolved dependencies
>   common/helpers (imported by src/components/Link/index.ts...

My rollup config

```js
/* eslint-disable flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation, no-console, import/extensions */
import nodeResolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import flow from "rollup-plugin-flow";
import sourceMaps from "rollup-plugin-sourcemaps";

const commonPlugins = [
  flow({
    pretty: true
  }),
  sourceMaps(),
  nodeResolve({
    jsnext: true,
    main: true,
    browser: true,
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
  }),
  babel({
    exclude: "node_modules/**"
  }),
  commonjs({
    namedExports: {
      react: [
        "cloneElement",
        "createFactory",
        "Component",
        "PropTypes",
        "createElement",
        "createContext"
      ],
      "react-dom": ["render"],
      "react-is": ["isElement", "isValidElementType", "ForwardRef"]
    }
  })
];

const globals = { react: "React", "react-dom": "ReactDOM" };

const configBase = {
  input: "./src/index.js",
  plugins: commonPlugins
};

const standaloneBaseConfig = {
  ...configBase,
  output: {
    file: "dist/package.js",
    format: "cjs",
    name: "sct",
    globals,
    sourcemap: true
  },
  plugins: configBase.plugins
};

export default standaloneBaseConfig;
```

Can I use absolгte paths in my project and how can resolve it?

Comment: "common/assets" isn't an absolute path. Where do those files live compared to the js file that references them?

Comment: @Tivac `../src/common/assets`. For webpack I use `resolve` directive as `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` for access to it in dev environment. Has rollupjs similar rule?

Comment: Yes, https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-alias

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official plugin for that: [@rollup/plugin-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias).